# How do you pause between cases in switch statements? c#. 3second delay before executing the next case

Tags: c#, timer, switch-statement, delay, picturebox

This is a sample of my code. I want to have a 3 second delay before executing the next case (display picturebox). But When I tried using timer/stopwatch, the 3 second delay will only be on the 1st case and case2 will execute the same time as case1 (with no delay).

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string input = (input1.Text).ToString();
    char[] letters = input.ToCharArray();
    int stringlength = letters.Length;
    int length = stringlength - 1;

    int state = 1;
    int position = 0;
    string validation = " ";


    switch (state)
    {
        case 1: 
            //insert timer here
            if (letters[position] == 'a')
            {

                pictureBox2.Visible = true;
                validation = "Invalid";
                label1.Text = validation;
                break;
            }
            else if (letters[position] == 'b')
            {
                if (position == length)
                {
                    validation = "Invalid";
                    label1.Text = validation;
                    break;
                }
                pictureBox2.Visible = true;
                position = position + 1;
                goto case 2;
            }
            break;

        case 2: 
            //Insert Timer here
            if (letters[position] == 'a')
            {
                pictureBox3.Visible = true;
                if (position == length)
                {
                    validation = "Invalid because it does not end at final state";
                    label1.Text = validation;
                    break;
                }
                position = position + 1;
                goto case 3;
            }
            else if (letters[position] == 'b')
            {
                if (position == length)
                {
                    validation = "Invalid";
                    label1.Text = validation;
                    break;
                }

                position = position + 1;
                goto case 4;
            }
            break;
    }

}
```

By the way, I can't use `Task.Delay` or `async/await` because I use the .Net 4.0 framework.

Comment: Do not use `goto` please.

Comment: Apart from the `goto` in a switch-case, why would you put a pause (then a timer) in each case? The `state` is already evaluated in `switch` and it's useless to put a timer in each case, so maybe you would put it before the `switch` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform this by using:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
```

So Your code should look like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int state = 1;
    //some code


    switch (state)
    {
        case 1:
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
         //some case code
         break;
        case 2:
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
         //some case code
         break;
       default:
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
         //some default code
         break;
    }
    //rest of the code
}
```

Just to let You know, there should be other (and better) way to going through this, rather than using switch and this type of GOTO case this and this. Making the code unreadable in future.

Comment: Just note that Thread.Sleep() will block all of the thread, if it is your UI.thread for example your application will feel like it is frozen during those 3 seconds of sleep. If that is what @Kate Lastimosa wants she can use Thread.Sleep() if not the idea of a Timer has been better suited.

Answer (score -1):

`Thread.Sleep(3000)` you can use

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: what is the reason for the down vote. Clearly I have mentioned in the comments after case statement op has to use Thread.Sleep